# Moving the line in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to implement the function of moving `newLine_MouseMove`, so that I could with the mouse to move the line around the Canvas, and not only in the lower right corner as shown in the `Code`:

[image]

**Code:**

```
private void newLine_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) //Movement only when the key is pressed
    {
        if (ExitLine())  //The function returns a value true, if the line is within the Canvas.
        {
            if (selectedLine != null) //If you select a line
            {
                //????????????????????
                /*
                selectedLine.X1 += 1;
                selectedLine.Y1 += 1;
                selectedLine.X2 += 1;
                selectedLine.Y2 += 1;
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would love to get a detailed answer.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a "stirred smooth line"? What is this code supposed to be doing? Do you really just want the line to move diagonally to the lower right as long as your `ExitLine()` method returns `true`? For a "detailed answer", I strongly recommend a detailed question. The two usually go hand in hand.

Comment: This code example moves the line in the lower right corner, and I need to move beyond the line of the mouse across the entire desktop display.

Comment: If you want the movement to follow the mouse, then you need to use the mouse coordinates (available in the `MouseEventArgs` object). Usually this means saving the coordinates when the mouse button is first pressed, and then using the difference between the current position and that start position to determine the actual change in the object position or boundary. But without a better question, it's impossible to know for sure what will work for you. What is `ExitLine()`? Why do you only move the object when that returns `true`?

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly for me.  You will need to change some of the code in the `<Window>` section, but leave the `MouseMove=""` definition there:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="525" Width="525"
        MouseMove="Line_MouseMove">

    <Line Name="L1" X2="50" Y2="50" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" />

</Window>
```

This is the definition of `Line_MouseMove`:

```
private void Line_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    L1.X2 = L1.X2 - L1.X1 + e.GetPosition(L1).X;
    L1.Y2 = L1.Y2 - L1.Y1 + e.GetPosition(L1).Y;
    L1.X1 = e.GetPosition(L1).X;
    L1.Y1 = e.GetPosition(L1).Y;
}
```

This is what is happening here.  This code creates the line: `<Line ... />`.  When your mouse is moving over the window, the window calls the `MouseMove` event, which calls the `Line_MouseMove` method.  The `Line_MouseMove` method adds the position of the cursor relative to the line to the `X` and `Y` coordinates, which maintains the length and angle of the line, but keeps the beginning position of the line the same.  To change the length and angle of the line, just change the values of `X2` and `Y2`.

If you need to limit the line to a certain area, replace `Line_MouseMove` with this:

```
private void Line_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // create limited rectangle
    Rect rr = new Rect(100, 50, 60, 400);

    // check if both ends of the line are fully contained within the rectangle
    if (rr.Contains(e.GetPosition(L1).X, e.GetPosition(L1).Y) && rr.Contains(e.GetPosition(L1).X + L1.X2 - L1.X1, e.GetPosition(L1).Y + L1.Y2 - L1.Y1))
    {
        // change the line's position
        L1.X2 = L1.X2 - L1.X1 + e.GetPosition(L1).X;
        L1.Y2 = L1.Y2 - L1.Y1 + e.GetPosition(L1).Y;
        L1.X1 = e.GetPosition(L1).X;
        L1.Y1 = e.GetPosition(L1).Y;
    }
}
```

Replace the coordinates in `Rect(0, 0, 200, 200)` with the coordinates you want - you may need to calculate them based on the window size.

The above solution allows the end of the line to disappear off the designated area.

Comment: I doubt that handling `MouseMove` event of `Line` won't work expectedly. Especially when you try moving the line as fast as possible.

Comment: @KingKing I'm not sure what you mean here.  Handling `MouseMove` in `Line` does not work, but handling it in `Window` does work.

Comment: Well the handler name in fact cheated me. its name is `Line_MouseMove` but in fact that's the `MouseMove` handler of the `Window`. So of course it works.

Comment: I tried to handle it in `Line`, but then changed it to the `Window`.

Comment: that's also what I did first but noticed the problem (when moving it as fast as possible).

Comment: @KingKing Do you know how I would handle this supposing I didn't want the line following me all over the window, just over a certain part of it?  Putting the `Line` in a `Grid` or `Canvas` inside the window doesn't work.

Comment: A simple solution is try checking if the position (is being set for the Line) should be confined to that certain part. The `Rect` structure has a very useful method called `Contains`. If the Point's contained in that Rect, set the position normally, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: OK, but what about resizing the window?  I suppose I could use ratios, like I would anyway to determine the size of the box.

Comment: I supposed the `Rect` is fixed. Resizing (shrinking) window would make the actual space smaller than the `Rect`, but I don't think the `Line` can be rendered outside the Window, also when the mouse is out of Window, the `MouseMove` event should not be fired.

Comment: I meant resizing larger.  Maybe we should discuss this in a chatroom.

Comment: In that case, you have to re-calculate the `Rect`. However using `Canvas` (wrapped inside a `Viewbox`) is a better choice. But note that you have to set `ClipToBounds` to `true` and try handling `MouseMove` of `Canvas` instead.

Comment: I think there are many approaches around this problem. So discussing is something too broad. Just try digging into it yourself. Talking like this is something theoretical.

Comment: Solved it, check the answer now.